# Julia: why must parametric types have outer constructors?

Tags: julia

The following works:

```
type TypeA
       x :: Array
       y :: Int
       TypeA(x :: Array ) = new(x, 2)
       end

julia> y = TypeA([1,2,3])
TypeA([1,2,3],2)
```

This does not:

```
type TypeB{S}
       x :: Array{S}
       y :: Int
       TypeB{S}( x:: Array{S} ) = new(x,2)
       end

julia> y = TypeB([1,2,3])
ERROR: `TypeB{S}` has no method matching TypeB{S}(::Array{Int64,1})
```

In order to get the second case to work, one has to declare the constructor outside of the type declaration. This is *slightly* undesirable.
My question is why this problem exists from a Julia-design standpoint so I can better reason about the Julia type-system.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works:

```
type TypeB{S}
    x::Array{S}
    y::Int
    TypeB(x::Array{S}) = new(x,2)
end
TypeB{Int}([1,2,3])
```

which I figured out by [reading the manual](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/constructors/), but I must admit I don't really understand inner constructors that well, especially for parametric types. I think its because you are actually defining a family of types, so the inner constructor is only sensible for each individual type - hence you need to specify the `{Int}` to say which type you want. You can add an outer constructor to make it easier, i.e.

```
type TypeB{S}
    x::Array{S}
    y::Int
    TypeB(x::Array{S}) = new(x,2)
end
TypeB{S}(x::Array{S}) = TypeB{S}(x)
TypeB([1,2,3])
```

I think it'd be good to bring it up on the Julia issues page, because I feel like this outer helper constructor could be provided by default.

EDIT: This [Julia issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/8234) points out the problems with providing an outer constructor by default.